# Error al querer editar fila en GridView con ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp

Habilite los campos IndexChanging, CancelilngEditing y RowUpdating, Al momento de dar clic sobre "Update" si muestra los labels y el texto en ellos pero cuandodoy en "Update" me tira una excepcion

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Este es mi codigo

```
protected void GridView2_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        bool IsUpdated = false;

        int ID = (int)GridView2.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value;
        int PAYROLL = (int)GridView2.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value;
        int POOL = (int)GridView2.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value;
        int TEAM = (int)GridView2.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value;
        int ROL = (int)GridView2.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value;

        TextBox WHO = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Tgv_who");
        TextBox NAME = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Tgv_name");
        TextBox OU = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Tgv_ou");

        string myConnectionString = @"C:\\Users\\gutiece\\Desktop\\database\\" + "Database1.accdb";

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection())
        {
            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data source= " + myConnectionString;
                command.Connection = connection;

                command.CommandText = "UPDATE users SET who = @who, payroll_number = @payroll, name = @name, ou = @ou, pool = @pool, team = @team, rol_id = @rol WHERE id = @id";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payroll", PAYROLL);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pool", POOL);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@team", TEAM);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rol", ROL);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@who", WHO);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", NAME);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ou", OU);

                connection.Open();
                IsUpdated = command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;

                GridView2.DataBind();
                Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: en que lugar tira ese error?

Comment: @ghianchi al momento de la ejecucion  del query... o sea en el ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: podrias aclarar como queda tu query (el string) hace algo como string query = "update user...." y agrega en la pregunta como queda el query... me parece que estas pasando objetos y no valores a la query...

Comment: @gabianchi acabo de actualizar el codigo, espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: espera.. esto no tiene nada que ver con el error de ayer??? como medida de orden, deberias haber dejado la pregunta anterior como estaba, dar una respuesta por valida (si ayudo a solucionar ese problema) y luego armar una pregunta nueva. por favor hace eso, y despues vemos cual es tu nuevo problema.

Comment: Oh lo siento, no tenia idea de que debia hacerlo de esa manera, en algun momento lo hice asi y la marcaron como pregunta repetida

Comment: debias estar preguntando lo mismo.. aca estas preguntando otra cosa, mas alla de que el codigo sea el mismo.. antes tenias un problema en la query, ahora tenes un problema con la grilla de entrada..

Answer (score 0):

Fijate que en tu consulta el query dice lo siguiente:

```
UPDATE users SET who = [@WHO], payroll_number = [@PAYROLL_NUMBER], name = [@NAME], ou = [@OU], pool = [@POOL], team = [@TEAM], rol_id = [@ROL_ID] WHERE id = id
```

y seguramente `WHERE id = id` este mal, pq id debe ser numerico, y problablemente querias pasar un Id para saber que registro modificar. Te esta faltando un parametro.

Comment: tengo el id en un campo hidden peo aun asi no me permite  cambiar la igormacion

Comment: es que id debe ser otro parametro mas!!! y ahi no lo estas mandando como parametro..

Comment: He modificado el codigo pero me sigue apareciendo el mismo error, acabo de actualizarlo tambien aqui `Data type mismatch in criteria expression.`

Answer (score 0):

Segun lo que puedo ver en tu codigo, todos los parametros los envias de tipo texto al colocarle las comillas simples ---> `'valor'` revisa si el procedimiento de actualizar en realidad recibe todos los parametros en tipo texto....si el parametro es de tipo fecha debes enviarlo como tipo fecha, igual si recibe un double, o un entero, o un byte, etc... deben ser del mismo tipo de dato

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Luis, de hecho si hay varios que son enteros, empero, los omito para que no me marque error de ellos, y aun asi persiste el error. Aunque aprovechando ¿como puedo convertirlos a enteros? He intentado de todas maneras y siempre marca un error

Comment: para convertir un valor puedes usar el `parse` o el `convert` por ejemplo

`Convert.ToInt16(valor)` 
`Int16.Parse(valor)`

Comment: y si son enteros largos usa:
`Convert.ToInt64(valor)`
`Int64.Parse(valor)`

Comment: por lo general yo uso el `Convert` porque el `parse` aveces me pone problemas

Comment: Si, de hecho lo he intentado con `convert` pero no se en que parte de `TextBox Tgv_id = (TextBox)row.FindControl("Tgv_id");` ponerlo

Comment: `"UPDATE users SET who = '"+ Tgv_who +"', payroll_number = '"+ Tgv_pay +"', name = '"+ Tgv_name +"', ou = '"+ Tgv_ou +"', pool = '"+ Tgv_pool +"', team = '"+ Tgv_team +"', rol_id = '"+ Tgv_rol +"' WHERE id = '"+ Tgv_id +"'";`
me refiero precisamente a estos parametros que estas enviando...aa todos les estas colocando las comillas simples fuera de las variables....--> `'" + hola mundo + "'` esas comillas simples que encierran a tus variables estan convirtiendo a texto todo el contendido....a los que no sean textos, quitales las comillas simples y dejalas como `..." + variable + " ...`

Comment: Lo hice como me dijiste y aun asi me tira una excepcion en la misma parte, hice un break en el query y si tiene todos los datos como los deberia tener pero al momento de la ejecucion de este, falla